# Error converting date and/or time from character string, VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, date, dateadd

I am currently working in visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop. I am having a problem with a fairly simple error. I am trying to run an sql command that selects a date from a date time picker and then sets the time to 6 am and 3 pm. Then the select query will pull all data entries between these times. However, my string is not converting to date time. I put a message box in and checked to make sure my string looked correct and it did. I also already put this sql code into my sql server management studio to double check it worked and it all went through fine. Here is my code:

```
   'SQL 1st shift statement
            'Eff Statement
            Dim Time As Date = DTPStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                conn1.Open()
                Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT ((sum([MINUTES])/60)/@HoursWorked) as Efficiency FROM table1 " _
                                              & "Left Join table2 on table1.PartNumber + '-' =table2.PART_NUMBER " _
                                              & "WHERE Time BETWEEN (DATEADD(HH, 6, @Start)) AND (DATEADD(HH, 15, @Start)) " _
                                              & "AND Sequence = 25 AND Assemble = 1 AND PartNumber is not null and [MINUTES] > 29", conn1)
                    comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", DTPStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HoursWorked", WorkingHours)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                    sql.Fill(dt)
                    Dim EFF As String = CDbl(dt.Rows(0)(0)).ToString("N2")
                    labeleff.Text = EFF
                End Using
                conn1.Close()
            End Using
```

This code should automatically generate an eff. number, however I will do many spin offs of this query.

Comment: In your SqlCommand you specify `@HoursWorked` as a parameter but use `@WorkHours` in your `AddWithValue`.

Comment: good catch but it is correct in my statement, will update.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to make your life simpler with this code.

Rather than concatenating a load of strings to create the SQL query, you can take advantages of VB.NET's ability to input XML directly - the only downside is using the <, > and & characters in XML.

There is no need to use SQL's methods to get the start and end times: you can do it in a more flexible fashion in your VB code.

As you apparently want only one result, you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it was designed for that.

Finally, I strongly recommend *not* using `AddWithValue` - it will come back to bite you at some time when it infers the wrong type to pass to the SQL server. It is better to add a New SqlParameter. Oh, and I have a suspicion that in the join you should be specifying `table1.Sequence` etc. rather than just `Sequence`.

So...

```
Dim dayStartTime As New TimeSpan(6, 0, 0)
Dim dayEndTime As New TimeSpan(15, 0, 0)

Dim theDate As DateTime = DTPStart.Value.Date
Dim startTime As DateTime = theDate.Add(dayStartTime)
Dim endTime As DateTime = theDate.Add(dayEndTime)

Dim workingHours As Double = (endTime - startTime).TotalHours

    ' N.B. As this is XML, you must use &lt; &gt; &amp; for <, >, & '
Dim sqlText = <sql>
                     SELECT (SUM([MINUTES]) / 60.0 / @HoursWorked) AS Efficiency FROM table1
                      LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.PART_NUMBER = table1.PartNumber + '-' 
                      WHERE [Time] BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime 
                        AND Sequence = 25
                        AND Assemble = 1
                        AND PartNumber IS NOT NULL
                        AND [MINUTES] &gt; 29
              </sql>.Value

Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
    Using comm1 As New SqlCommand(sqlText, conn1)

        comm1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@StartTime", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = startTime})
        comm1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@EndTime", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = endTime})
        comm1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@HoursWorked", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Float, .Value = workingHours})

        conn1.Open()
        Dim efficieny As Object = comm1.ExecuteScalar
        conn1.Close()

        If efficieny IsNot Nothing Then
            labeleff.Text = CDbl(efficieny).ToString()
        Else
            ' query did not return a result '
        End If

    End Using

End Using
```

**ETA:** Oh, and the most important bit, do not use strings for dates. Doing that is just asking for problems.